# Kendo multiselect not persisting previously selected value

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm using kendo multiselect dropdown - the issue I'm facing is when I select a dropdown value and after submit when I reopen the page the previously selected value is no longer selected. I tired using localStorage but it did not work for me, can anyone help me how can this can be achieved. I've added a sample code

```html
<kendo-multiselect
    k-data-value-field="'emptype'"
    k-data-text-field="'emptype'"
    k-ng-model="empbatch.emptype"
    k-ng-delay="emptypedatasource"
    k-data-source="emptypedatasource" 
    ng-required="true"
    k-on-change="selectedtype(empbatch.emptype)"
    k-placeholder="'Select options...'">
</kendo-multiselect>


.controller('YourController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 
   

    // Function to handle the selected type
    $scope.selectedtype = function(value) {
    //when dropdown is selected it comes to this function
        var empDept = value.map(item => item.DEPT);
        $scope.empDeptfield = empDept.join(', ');

      
    };
$scope.emptypedatasource={
//rest callresponse){return reponse.data}

}]);
```